# Acceso bloqueado a Socket servidor

Tags: python, servidor, socket, websocket, puertos

En Python se ha creado un script que me abre un puerto a demanda en mi máquina linux, la recepción, respuesta, cierre de sesión y almacén de datos anda bien, pero cada cierto tiempo el socket se bloquea y por ende deja de recibir datos. He leido que mientras haya una sesión establecida el socket se bloquea e impide nuevas conexiones. ¿Hay alguna forma de impedir el bloqueo del puerto? de forma que al haber una sesión establecida aún pueda recibir mensajes por el mismo puerto?

El código es el siguiente:

De antemano agradezco la ayuda

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import socket 
from threading import Thread
import threading
import time
import argparse
import multiprocessing as mp
import thread
import subprocess
import codecs
import traceback

print_lock = threading.Lock() 

class SocketServer():
    '''
    This class creates a socket server and listens to messages on a specific ip and port.
    '''
    clients = []

    def __init__(self, ip='127.0.0.1', port='8080', folder_path='data', timer=60):
        '''
        Parameters

        ip: int
            Ip to receive messages with web socket.
        port: int
            Port to receive messages with web socket.
        folder_path: string
            Path to save messages received with web socket.
        timer: int
            Timer to wait to last messages or close connection with client.
        '''
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        self.timer = timer
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        #self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port)) 

        self.socket.listen(5) 


        def run(self):
            print ("Server started")
        try:
            self.accept_clients()
        except Exception as ex:
            print (ex)
        finally:
            print ("Server closed")
            for client in self.clients:
                client.close()
            self.socket.close()

    def accept_clients(self):
        '''
        Accet client to connect this and create thread to process client.
        '''
        while 1:
            print("Multithreaded Python server : Waiting for connections in IP:", self.ip, " PORT:",self.port)
            print_lock.acquire() 
            (clientsocket, address) = self.socket.accept()
            clientsocket.settimeout(self.timer)
            #Adding client to clients list
            self.clients.append(clientsocket)
            #Client Connected
            self.onopen(clientsocket, address)
            #Receiving data from client
            thread.start_new_thread(self.receive, (clientsocket,address))

    def receive(self, client, address):
        '''
        Receive messages from client trough onmessage and onclose
        '''
        data_brute=''
        max_buffer_size = 1024
        try:
            while 1:
                data_brute, port  = client.recvfrom(max_buffer_size)
                if not data_brute:
                    break   
                else:
                    #Message Received
                    self.onmessage(client, data_brute, address)
            self.onclose(client,address, data_brute)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()       
            #Client Disconnected
            self.onclose(client,address, data_brute)


    def onopen(self, client, address):
        '''
        Trigger when new client connected.
        '''
        print ("[+] New server socket thread started for " + str(address))

    def onmessage(self, client, message, address):
        '''
        Trigger when response to client with a message.
        '''
        self.save_data(address[0], message)
        MESSAGE = b'\nMessage received by server\n'
        client.send(MESSAGE)  # echo

    def onclose(self, client, address, data):
        '''
        Trigger to print close connection with client.
        '''
        print("Close connection",address, data)
        print_lock.release() 
        #Removing client from clients list
        self.clients.remove(client)
        #Closing connection with client
        client.close()
        #Closing thread
        thread.exit()    

    def save_data(self, addr, data):
        '''
        Save in txt and call php function when receive data from client.

        Parameters
        ----------
        addr: tuple int (ip,port)
            Address from connected client

        data: bytes
            Data send from client to server.
        '''
        #Save data in txt and log adding lines to document.
        file_path = os.path.join(self.folder_path,'data.txt')
        log_path = os.path.join('log','log.txt')

        data_decode = data

        if not os.path.isdir(self.folder_path):
            os.makedirs(self.folder_path)

        if not os.path.isdir('log'):
            os.makedirs('log')

        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:            
            file.write('#'+data_decode+'\n') 

        with open(log_path, 'a') as file:
            file.write(dt_string +','+data_decode+'\n')

        subprocess.call(["php", "thingsend.php"])


def main(ip='127.0.0.1',port=18003, folder_path='data'): 
    '''
    Funtion principal to create object SocketServer from websocket.
    '''              
    # Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
    SocketServer(ip, port, folder_path)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('parameters',
                        type=str, nargs=3,
                        help='host, port and folder')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ip = args.parameters[0]
    port = int(args.parameters[1])
    folder_path = os.path.abspath(args.parameters[2])

    server_process = mp.Process(name="{server_socket}",
                                 args=(ip, port, folder_path),
                                 target=main)
    server_process.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema no esta en que se bloquee el puerto, esto es un comportamiento normal tu problema probablemente es que te quedas sin conexiones o el proceso en si dejó de responder, en tu caso son 5 conexiones disponibles, si se conecta un sexto no podrá hacerlo ya que se ha alcanzado el máximo.

te recomiendo el uso de esta librería para evitar este tipo de problemas y que tu foco este en tu lógica de negocio:

https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html